# I don't have access to get all invitable_friends at Facebook API

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get all facebook invitable friends, yesterday it was working, but today the facebook API has return that

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) No permission to access invitable_friends.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "ApJrz2NAGPx"
  }
}
```

I think it would be a error in my facebook app, but when I went at facebook graph API explorer, I saw error occurs for my all applications.

What can it be?

Comment: Are your applications games? The docs indicate the permission is only valid for game applications.

Comment: Yes, I was change the application to game, yesterday it was works, but today no

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Is it *actually* a game? Or did you just say it was one to get access to that API?

Comment: The application is in the "games" category currently.
I changed to get access to invitable_friends

Comment: IS IT **ACTUALLY** A GAME?

Comment: No, it is not a **game**, but it is in the games category, I changed to get access to invitable_friends permission.

Comment: You got caught.

Answer (score 1):

> No, it is not a game, but it is in the games category, I changed to get access to `invitable_friends` permission.

Chances are they caught you, and you've lost access. Be glad that's the only sanction they applied.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But do you know a way to get all facebook friends without invitable_friends?

Comment: @JosephF. No. Facebook has intentionally and firmly restricted this privilege. It is no longer possible. That should be pretty clear from the workaround you attempted to use. They consider it to be private information, as the user's friends have not authorized your application and may not have any interest in their data being accessible to you.